# What is best for register section labels? "Your email" or "Email"

Tags: usability, navigation, registration, wording

I don't even know if it makes any difference but I read an article about how you should always write in a way the user feels like you are talking directly to him so I wonder if this applies to every site component like labels for register forms.

So, if there is a better one, which one is it?

Comment: Remember to be consistent if you're using "your." Some sites switch between that and "my," which makes the site sound schizophrenic: "Your Preferences" and "My Shopping Cart," etc. (Who's speaking? Who is "me"?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Brand voice is experience too

Interface copy needs to be concise so users can easily scan for recognizable points of action. However, you do have room for expression within that limitation. An experienced brand team that understands more than advertising can go a long way here.

Let's look at your two examples. A seemingly small change, but when carried throughout the UI a message is being sent.

- **“Email”** is as concise as it gets. This app is all business. In this environment, you will be efficient and productive. This app isn't going to condescend you with any frilly instructive language -- it expects that you know what you're doing.
  I might also expect to find "Register", "Logout", "Upload".
- **“Your email”** is short, but with a hint of humanity. It's less like filling out a government form, more like your local dentist's office. Not that anyone is going to ask *"Who's email!?"*, but it suggests that the app is thinking about *me* as the user.
  I might expect to find "Sign up", "Sign out", "Upload a document".

## Everything in context

This one label isn't going to change the whole tone of your app — the important thing is to send a consistent and correct message with your language throughout. I've created some fairly personable, quirky experiences that used concise labels due to form density. The trick there was to reinforce the personality with the explanatory copy and title text.

Comment: That's a good point. As you said, it feels like "your email" has a hint of humanity. This might be out of the scope of this post but what if you change it to "my [email/user/password/credit card]"? Wouldn't the user fell "home" or something like that because the addition of "my"?
And as Eric mentioned, how much is too much? If you have 10 elements with "my" before (or even "your") it might feel kinda overwhelming or feel too much.

Comment: @LucianoInfanti ime, using the first person (eg 'my') just sounds weird. You are asking for something, they aren't independently choosing to store it.

Comment: @LucianoInfanti To your point about pronoun overkill, that relates to what I was saying about dense forms. Sometimes it's better to let the fields be neutral and handle personality elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If the point of this section of your site is to register the user, why not to title it something more specific like "Sign up" or "Register now"? Both of the labels you are considering seem a bit ambiguous, perhaps more like field labels than section titles.

Presumably there is more to registration than just entering email… If not, perhaps something more like "Enter your email," or "What is your email address?" might be clearer for the user.

Comment: The section title is register but in this section I have a few labels for email, name and password. So, my question is if I call the email label "Your email" (same thing applies to name and password) would that be better in terms of user experience?

Comment: I'd say it's probably a question of site tone and how concise you feel you need to be. At the end of the day, I don't think any user, seeing a field labeled "Email" in a section about registration, will be confused as to what they need to do. "Your email" is a BIT more personal, and "Please enter your email" is more conversational still... But depending on the standards you've set, it might be too chatty and wordy. You might consider a simpler label and then some placeholder text in the field with more info, if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Content of the website or web app depends on kind of experience you want for them.
Examples:
The content strategy for serious business apps like freshdesk can be direct and concise. You can encounter words like "Sign Up" instead of register now.
In case of facebook, they are trying to use pleasing wording "Sign Up" it is free and always will be.

Comment: So, if I'm designing a small startup website and I want my clients to be really close to the company I should try something less formal to be consistent with the kind of relationship I want to build. Is that correct? By the way, thanks for your answer!

Comment: Depends on the kind of customer experience you want to give and TG you have.

Answer (score 1):

How about adding an introductory instruction statement below the form title but above all the fields?

*Ex. 1*

**Register Here**

Enter your information below:

**Name**:

**Email**:

etc.

If you're wanting company details, you'll need to be specific about whose or what's information is being requested. The person filling out the form in the example below should easily understand they are being asked for their name. Assistants completing these forms will simply use their boss's name (cued by the request for title).

*Ex. 2*

**Register Here**

Enter applicable information below:

**Name**: (If you think there is any possibility of confusion here, add Your)

**Company Name**:

**Your Title**:

**Company Email**:

Clearly defining the who and what of requested input is always appreciated by users who are interested in revealing their information.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say adding "your" is only clutter unless you need to distinguish it from something else that may not be proper to the user.

If you say "Your email," is not everything else proper to the user? So then would you append "Your to everything -- your address, your username, your password, your profile, your settings, your credit card number, your file to upload, your keyboard... Is there anything in the application that could not have "Your" prepended? Or why only choose some things arbitrarily to append with "Your"?

Better to omit it altogether and avoid visual clutter that would otherwise become laughable unless applied randomly.